# Capistrano 3 does not restart my rails app after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I use the following deploy.rb :

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'
set :application, '*****'
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :repo_url, 'admin@test.*******.***:/srv/outils/repos/*****'
set :scm, :git

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
  #after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
end
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

It correctly deploy the app but does not restart it. What should i modify to make it restart? There is no message, error or otherwise, about the restart.

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In Capistrano 3, the `restart` task is available and will be called, but it is empty. See the Capistrano source code in [capistrano/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake) for the code:

```
[...]

  task :restart
  task :failed

end
```

If you want the `restart` task to actually do something, you can change the default behavior for `restart` by adding this code to your `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    invoke rake-restart-something-task
  end
end
```

Where the `rake-restart-something-task` can be something like `deploy:service:restart_apache`, or some other task that you defined in the capistrano rake file.